# Average swaps needed for a random bubble sort algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains, expected-value, random-walk, sorting

Suppose we have $n$ elements in a random permutation (each permutation has equal probability initially). While the elements are not fully sorted, we swap two *adjacent* elements at random (e.g. the permutation $(1, 3, 2)$ can go to $(1, 2, 3)$ or $(3, 1, 2)$ with equal probability $0.5$). How many times does it take on average to fully sort the $n$ elements?

For the case $n=2$, there is a $0.5$ chance that the elements are already sorted, in which case $0$ swaps are needed, and a $0.5$ chance that the two elements are swapped, in which case a single swap is needed to bring the elements back into order, in which case you need $1$ swap, so you need on average $0.5$ swaps.

For the case $n=3$, I used a Markov chain to represent the possible permutations, and (sparing the details) I found that on average $5\frac{5}{6}$ swaps would be needed to get the $3$ elements in order.

For $n\geq4$ it is too difficult to manually construct Markov chains representing the permutations, but I noticed:

- The [inversion number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)#Inversion_number) always changes by exactly $1$
- From any given state, there are $n-1$ possible states you can transition to

Any ideas for getting a closed form on the expected number of swaps?

Comment: I meant adjacent pairs. I apologise for not making it clear.

Comment: +1 All clear now; nice question!

Comment: Why does the inversion number always increase by $1$? It could instead decrease by $1$ too, right?

Comment: The Markov chain approach might be more manageable if you use induction and stick with $2\times2$-matrices, distinguishing between permutations  that fix the last element and permutations that do not. The details may still get a bit sticky though, not sure, so I'll leave it at a comment for now.

Comment: If you model each permutation as a vertex in a graph, you have a $n-1$ regular graph with one special vertex corresponding to the sorted permutation. So the question becomes the expected number of steps needed to get to that special vertex via a random walk, where the expectation is take over all possible starting locations. The tricky part is given a vertex, how does one determine its distance to that special vertex...

Comment: Solving the system of equations with Mathematica gives an expected number of $\frac{1019}{28}$ swaps when $n=4$; $\frac{73483980061}{379029420}$ swaps when $n=5$; approximately $1079.44$ when $n=6$; approximately $6886.87$ when $n=7$.

Comment: @VTand That's another mistake I made in my post. Of course it can decrease by $1$ too, because otherwise unless you already start out with the sorted permutation you can't sort anything! (also thank you Misha)

Comment: @Kyky would you be happy with asymptotics or just a closed form?

Comment: I'd prefer closed form if possible, but I'd award the bounty to asymptotics if that's the only answer I get by the end of the bounty.

Comment: The sorted array has 0 inversions, this should help

Comment: Does the swap occur when two adjacent list elements are selected randomly, or only when the two adjacent list elements are out of order?  In conventional bubble sort, an upper bound for the number of swaps would be nC2, the number of swaps required when the list is in reverse order.  So for n=4, the upper bound would be 6.  Efficient testing for when the list is sorted introduces further interesting programming challenges.

Comment: @richard1941 I mean the former. A question about "conventional" bubble sort is probably a lot easier, and I suspect that you could probably use some symmetry argument about the number of states with a given inversion number to show that for "conventional" bubble sort the expected no. of swaps should be $\frac{\binom{n}{2}}{2}$.

Comment: I've just seen the question, and got the details rather from the comments. To be sure that i am understanding the question correctly, before starting to work on the problem - the statement is as follows, focusing on the randomness. We are working with the space $S(n)$ with $n!$ elements of permutations of the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and pick at start a random permutation. We start a random walk at this random permutation. The step from time $t$ to $t+1$ is as follows. Say we are in $\sigma$ at time $t$. We look at all adjacent places $i$ and $i+1$ of $\sigma$ such that what happens?

Comment: ... (continued) if we are for instance with the situation $n=9$ and $\sigma$ corresponds to $\boxed{9}2345678\boxed{1}$, what are we allowing for adjacent positions to be "moved"? Same question for $123\boxed{9}5678\boxed{4}$. Same question for $123\boxed{7}56\boxed{4}89$.

Comment: @dan_fulea we can swap any two adjacent elements. So, from starting out from $923456781$ we can go to $293456781, 932456781, 924356781, \cdots, 923456718$. For $123956784$ we can go to $213956784, 132956784, 129356784, \cdots, 123956748$. For $123756489$ we can go to $213756489, 132756489, 127356489, \cdots, 123756498$.

Comment: I note that the graph of transitions is regular (n-1 transpositions) and bipartite (odd and even permutations)

Comment: Out of curiosity, if we allow all swaps (between any pair of elements, not only consecutive ones), does the problem become much easier? I think explicit computations are possible in this other setting, but maybe it makes the problem 'trivial' and I don't see it

Comment: When does the algorithm terminate (if ever)?

Comment: @charmd for that case there isn't an explicit formula, and the best asymptote I found was [$n!+(n-2)!+o((n-2)!)$](http://www.hermann-gruber.com/pdf/fun07-final.pdf).

Comment: @richard1941 Doesn't really matter, as long as it's not before we reach a sorted state. So you could, for instance, say that the algorithm halts when a sorted state is reached and ask for the expected time for the halting of the algorithm, or you could just assume the algorithm never ends and ask how long it takes for the algorithm to sort everything.

Comment: Actually the asymptote mentioned above should be $n!+2(n-2)!+o((n-2)!)$, my bad.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think one can prove that the average hitting time of the identity is at most something like $4n^2$ times the known asymptotic for the average hitting time when allowed to transition via any random transposition. This is because both these quantities are expressible via eigenvalues (see Chapter 12 of Levin, Peres, Wilmer) and one can use classical results on comparisons of Markov chains to argue that the relevant inverse eigengaps can be at most $4n^2$ larger in the random walk you're interested in compared to the one with all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S(n)$ be the symmetric group of the set $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$.

It acts on "words" of length $n$ with the letters $1,2,\dots$ taken each exactly once
by permuting corresponding *places*. A permutation will be identified with its action / its result on the
"first word" $12\dots n$. There are $n!$ such words, each is an anagram of the first word.

This answer computes explicitly and exactly **for small values of** $\bf n$
the mean time to reach the permutation $e=()=12\dots n$, which is the neutral element written in alternative notations,
when performing a random walk starting from a random element in $S(n)$ / from an anagram.
The steps of the random walk correspond to switching two adjacent places in the word.

For very small values, the structure is described, and computations are done easily by hand.
However for bigger values, there is no chance. So a computer aided answer is given for those cases,
so that we have exact answers from the linear systems extracted from the Markovian structure.
My choice of a computer algebra system is [sage](https://www.sagemath.org), since open source and object oriented.

---

Here are some general conventions first, we try to use standard terminology.
The group $S(n)$ is a Weyl group of type $A_{n-1}$, its *simple reflections* are
$$
s_j = s(j) = (j, j+1)\ ,\qquad 1\le j< n\ .
$$
(There are $(n-1)$ such reflections, this is also the index in the type.)
Depending on the context, the notation $s(j)$ may be better (instead of $s_j$),
because the index $j$ is the main feature, so it is not a good idea to show it smaller.
Each permutation has a writing as a product of minimal length of these generators
taken in a specific order.
(There may be one or more such writings.)
In case a (non-commutative) "word" $w\in S(n)$ (with alphabet having letters among the simple reflection) is
$$
w = s_is_j\dots s_k\ ,
$$
we will alternatively write it as
$$
w = s(i,j,\dots,k)\ ,
$$
and even - in case of no possible confusion - as $s(ij\dots k)$.
In case we use this notation, minimal product representations should be used.
(So $s(11)$ is not what we want to write.)

Note the (braid) relations $s(121)=s(212)$, $s(232)=s(323)$, and so on.

Computations will be done in sage. Sage has its own convention(s) to write permutations and work with them.
Since below we use code to write down examples, i will use also these conventions.
For instance, consider the permutation $p$ that brings the ordered list $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)$ into the list
$(1,2,3,8,5,6,7,4,9)$. Then we will use for $p$ also this representation as *word*, $p=123856749$.

On it we can action by the simple reflections from the left.
For instance:

```
sage: W = SymmetricGroup(9)
sage: p = Permutation([1,2,3,8,5,6,7,4,9])
sage: W(p)
(4,8)
sage: s1 = W.simple_reflections()[1]
sage: s2 = W.simple_reflections()[2]
sage: s3 = W.simple_reflections()[3]
sage: s3 * W(p)
(3,8,4)
sage: (s3 * W(p)).tuple()
(1, 2, 8, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 9)
sage: # so 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 5, 6 -> 6, 7 -> 7, 8 -> 4, 9 -> 9
sage: (s2*(s3 * W(p))).tuple()
(1, 8, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 9)
sage: ((s2*s3) * W(p)).tuple()
(1, 8, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 9)

sage: s7 = W.simple_reflections()[7]
sage: (s7*W(p)).tuple()
(1, 2, 3, 8, 5, 6, 4, 7, 9)
```

So this is a left action on "places".
For this action, the composition is a composition of fuctions acting on places.
In order to make this convention work, note that $s_2s_3=(23)(34)$ is $(2,4,3)$.

There is an other convention, also the one i like, where the permutations are function, and their composition is a composition of functions.
However, this is not what we want here. To have it explicitly:

```
sage: s2, s3, s2*s3
((2,3), (3,4), (2,4,3))

sage: s2(s3(4))
2
sage: (s2*s3)(4)
3
```

---

On $W=S(n)$ we have a (weak) Bruhat order.
See also the [Wiki page on the Bruhat order(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_order).

It is the order given by writing words $w\in W$
in terms of the simple reflection generators. For a simple reflection $s$ and a word $w$ the elements
$w$ and $sw$ are in relation. If $w$ has a (i.e. at least one) minimal writing that starts with $s$, then we set
$$ sw \prec w\ .
$$
Else, prepending $s$ makes each writing "longer" and we define
$$
w \prec sw\ .
$$
Let $\le$ be the relation obtained by closing the relation $\prec$ to an order relation, the (weak left) Bruhat order we are working with.
(We add transitivity, and reflexivity.)

With respect to this order, we have an oriented graph, the (oriented) Bruhat graph.
Its vertices are the elements of $W=S(n)$, its edges are corresponding to the simple relations $sw\prec w$ or $w\prec sw$ (only one holds) from above.
Its unoriented version is the graph we consider in the problem, so the Bruhat graph is this one below. Its
edges have natural labels $s$, simple reflections, in order to move from one vertex to the other one one multiplies from the right with $s$.
The "word length" either increases or decreases by one, $l(sw)=l(w)\pm 1$.

There are standard properties of this order. For instance, taking final subwords of a minimal word lead to Bruhat-smaller words.

---

Our problem is related to a random walk on this graph, each step having length one.
The question asks for the expected time needed to entry the set $\{e\}$ consisting of the neutral element only.

---

Although simple, let us consider first the case $n=3$ in detail to illustrate the structural situation in other cases, where propositions are not so simple.

**n = $\bf 3$**

There are $6=3!$ elements in $S(3)$. We denote the two transpositions or simple reflections $(12)=213$ and $(23)=132$ by $s_1=s(1)$, and respectively $s_2=s(2)$.
Each element can then be written in a minimal (length) fashion as a product of $s_1,s_2$. Explicitly:
$$
\begin{aligned}
()    &= 123 = e = s()\ , \\
(12)  &= 213 = s_1=s(1)\ , \\
(23)  &= 132 = s_2=s(2)\ , \\
(132) &= 312 = (12)(23) = s_1s_2=s(1,2)=s(12)\ , \\
(123) &= 213 = (23)(12) = s_2s_1=s(2,1)=s(21)\ , \\
(13)  &= 321 = s_1s_2s_1=s_2s_1s_2=s(1,2,1)=s(2,1,2)=s(121)=s(212)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(Some of the above lines have the meaning of an implicit **notation**.)

The corresponding Bruhat graph is:

```
        s()
       /   \
     2/     \1
     /       \ 
  s(2)       s(1)
   |           |
  1|           |2
   |           |
  s(12)      s(21)
    \         /
    2\       /1
      \     /
      s(121)
```

Let $N_w$ or $N(I)=N_w$ if $w=s(I)$, be the expected number of steps to go from the permutation $w$ to the neutral element $e$.
Here, if $I$ is a multiindex choice of simple reflections, $I=(i,j,\dots,k)$ we denote by $s(I)=s_is_j\dots s_k$.
Then we have the following system of equations to solve:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
N_e = N() &= 0\ ,\\
N(1) &= 1 + \frac 12N()  + \frac 12 N(12)\ ,\\
N(2) &= 1 + \frac 12N()  + \frac 12 N(21)\ ,\\
N(12) &= 1 + \frac 12N(1) + \frac 12 N(121)\ ,\\
N(21) &= 1 + \frac 12N(2) + \frac 12 N(121)\ ,\\
N(121) &= 1 + \frac 12N(12) + \frac 12 N(21)\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
(In fact, we do not need to solve this system explicitly, we need only the value
$\displaystyle \frac 1{3!}(\ N()+N(1)+N(2)+N(12)+N(21)+N(121)\ )$.)

```
var('x,x1,x2,x12,x21,x121');
solve( [x == 0, x1 == 1 + (x + x12)/2, x2 == 1 + (x + x21)/2,
        x12 == 1 + (x1 + x121)/2, x21 == 1 + (x2 + x121)/2, 
        x121 == 1 + (x12 + x21)/2, ],
        [x, x1, x2, x12, x21, x121] )
```

The solution is:

```
    [[x == 0, x1 == 5, x2 == 5, x12 == 8, x21 == 8, x121 == 9]]
```

And we build the sum $0+(5+5)+(8+8)+9=35$, so the expected mean is
$\displaystyle\frac {35}6\approx 5.8333\dots$ .

From the above we want to extract only the "cellular" structure, there are four cells, coincidently
corresponding here to the four possible lengths of a word. The cells and the transitions between them are as follows:

```
    s()

    A |
1/2 | | 1
    | V
    
s(1), s(2)

    A |
1/2 | | 1/2
    | V

s(12), s(21)

    A |
  1 | | 1/2
    | V

  s(121)
```

So we have to solve a simpler system, using $M_l$ for the cell with words of length $l$:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
N_0 &= 0\ ,\\
N_1 &= 1 + \frac 12 N_0 +\frac 12 N_2\ ,\\ 
N_2 &= 1 + \frac 12 N_1 +\frac 12 N_3\ ,\\ 
N_3 &= 1 + N_2\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Its solution is of course the "same" one, $N_0=0$, $N_1=5$, $N_2=8$, $N_3=9$, so counting each cell
weighted corresponding to the number of its elements,

---

The next case is slightly more complicated.

**n = $\bf 4$**

There are $24=4!$ elements in $S(4)$. We have three simple reflections.
The elements have the following representations (code and results):

```
sage: W = WeylGroup('A3')
sage: elements = list(W)
sage: elements.sort(key=lambda w: w.length())
sage: for w in elements:
....:     print(' = '.join([''.join([str(j) for j in word]) for word in w.reduced_words()]))
....: 

3
2
1
32
23
21
31 = 13
12
321
232 = 323
231 = 213
132 = 312
123
121 = 212
2321 = 3213 = 3231
2312 = 2132
1321 = 3212 = 3121
3123 = 1323 = 1232
1213 = 1231 = 2123
32132 = 21321 = 23121 = 23212 = 32312
12321 = 31231 = 13231 = 31213 = 13213 = 32123
12132 = 21323 = 23123 = 12312 = 21232
312312 = 213213 = 321232 = 312132 = 132132 = 323123 = 231213 = 212321 = 121321 = 321323 = 123212 = 123121 = 213231 = 231231 = 232123 = 132312
```

(The first empty line stays for the neutral element.)
The "cells" are now harder to be isolated and shown. At the beginning there is no problem.

```
    ()
    
    A|
  1 || 1
    |V
    
  1, 2, 3
```

But now we have to separate

```
 1_________  __2__  _________3
 |         \/     \/         |
2|        1/\3   1/\3        |2
 V        /  \   /  \        V
21     12   13=31    32      23
```

The entry $13=31$ is not "like the other" length two entries,
since it has two possible beginnings.
From here, we know that each of the entries $21$, $12$; $23$, $32$ is connected
to two words of lenght three, while $13=31$ connects to only one such entry in the Bruhat graph.

In length $3$ we have a similar separation. We show only how the entries connect to lower and higher length levels.

```
1\     /2 2\     /3      |3         |1      1\     /3      |2
  \   /     \   /        |          |         \   /        |
   \ /       \ /         |          |          \ /         |
   121       232        321        123         132        213
  =212      =323        / \        / \        =312       =231     
    |         |        /   \      /   \         |         / \      
    |         |      1/     \2  2/     \3       |        /   \    
    |3        |1                                |2     1/     \3
```

It is not easy to draw the graph.
We have only a symmetry corresponding to $s_1\leftrightarrow s_3$ that we can use.
Doing this, we still obtain some graph that can be traced back humanly. Each entry
has now representatives shown in a single writing.
Only some vertices are drawn.

```
         ____e____
        /         \
       /           \
      /             \
  1, 3___            2
   |     \           |
   |      \          |
   |       \         |
 21, 23     13  ____12, 32
   |  \      \ /       |
   |   \ _____X        |
   |    X      \       |
   |   / \      \      |
  121,/   123, 213    132
  323     321   |      |
   |     /  \   |      |
   |    /    \  |      |
   |   /      \ |      |
   1321,     1213,    2132
   1323      2321     /
    \         \ _____/
     \     ____X 
      \   /     \
     12132,    12321
     23212       /
        \       /
         \     /
          121321
```

This leads to a system with $15$ unknowns to be solved.
I will solve the system with all $24$ equations using code. But
it is good to see that the solutions respect this and only this symmetry!
The code is as follows:

```
def expected_steps(n):
    W = WeylGroup(['A', n-1])
    w_list = list(W)
    w_list.sort(key=lambda w: w.length())
    
    for w in w_list:
        exec("var('x{}')".format(''.join([str(j) for j in w.reduced_word()])))
    
    class WE(object):
        """Associate to each w in W an instance with some more needed structure.
        WE is a short cut for Weyl element.
        """
        def __init__(self, w):
            self.w = w
            self.varname = 'x' + (''.join([str(j) for j in w.reduced_word()]))
            self.var = eval(self.varname)
    
    vars = [WE(w).var for w in w_list]
    eqs  = [ WE(W.one()).var == 0 ] \
           + [ WE(w).var == 1 + 1/(n-1) * sum([WE(s*w).var for s in W.simple_reflections()])
               for w in w_list if w != W.one()]
    
    sol = solve(eqs, vars, solution_dict=True)[0]
    return sol
```

Then `sol = expected_steps(4)` gives:

```
sage: sol
    {x: 0,
     x3: 625/28,
     x2: 341/14,
     x1: 625/28,
     x32: 981/28,
     x23: 981/28,
     x21: 981/28,
     x31: 405/14,
     x12: 981/28,
     x321: 1153/28,
     x232: 1081/28,
     x231: 274/7,
     x312: 274/7,
     x123: 1153/28,
     x121: 1081/28,
     x2321: 171/4,
     x2312: 621/14,
     x3121: 171/4,
     x1232: 171/4,
     x1231: 171/4,
     x23121: 1273/28,
     x12321: 629/14,
     x12312: 1273/28,
     x123121: 324/7}
```

So the expected number of steps needed to reach $e$ starting from a random element is:

```
sage: sum(sol.values())/factorial(4)
1019/28
```

---

The next case is more complicated, although the same code leads to a quick solution.

**n = $\bf 5$**

We get:

```
sage: 
sage: sol = expected_steps(5)
sage: sol
{x: 0,
 x3: 3860770457/31585785,
 x2: 3860770457/31585785,
 x4: 3656646373/31585785,
 x1: 3656646373/31585785,
 x32: 10793324539/63171570,
 x34: 1486245371/9024510,
 x23: 10793324539/63171570,

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

 x1234312: 6637368586/31585785,
 x23412312: 13606936667/63171570,
 x23423121: 13500639197/63171570,
 x23412321: 1355491084/6317157,
 x12342312: 1355491084/6317157,
 x12341231: 13500639197/63171570,
 x34123121: 13500639197/63171570,
 x12342321: 13419193339/63171570,
 x12343121: 13419193339/63171570,
 x12341232: 13500639197/63171570,
 x234123121: 6825812773/31585785,
 x123412312: 6825812773/31585785,
 x123423121: 88342141/410205,
 x123412321: 88342141/410205,
 x1234123121: 15737160/72611}
sage:
```

I see no way to organize combinatorially the values obtained without a deep
(group-theoretical) insight.
For instance, the common denominator is:

```
sage: lcm([val.denominator() for val in sol.values() if val])
63171570
sage: ZZ(_).factor()
2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 23 * 29 * 41
```

The mean expectation is:

```
sage: sum(sol.values())/120
73483980061/379029420
```

One observation we make is that the expected number of steps
to go from $w$ to $e$ is the same as when we go from $w^{-1}$ to $e$.

---

**n = $\bf 6$**

The case is even more complicated from the combinatorial point of view.
However the linear algebra exercise is still easy for the computer.

```
sage: sol = expected_steps(6)
sage: sum(sol.values()) / factorial(6)
1105216051055620235300660929/1023883272960409990968840

sage: _.n()
1079.43559607146
```

We can still hope to see some structure from the factorization of the denominator.
But...

```
sage: QQ(sum(sol.values()) / factorial(6)).denominator()
1023883272960409990968840
sage: QQ(sum(sol.values()) / factorial(6)).denominator().factor()
2^3 * 3^3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19 * 23 * 29 * 41 * 61 * 67 * 71 * 1931 * 3253
```

There was an observation in case $n=5$, that the expected number of steps
steps to go from $w$ to $e$ is the same as when going from $w^{-1}$ to $e$.
Let us verify it here.

```
W = WeylGroup('A5')
w_list = list(W)
w_list.sort(key=lambda w: w.length())

ok = True
for w in w_list:
    we1, we2 = WE(w), WE(w^-1)
    if we1.varname < we2.varname:
        if sol[we1.var] == sol[we2.var]:
            print('OK :: same value {} for {} and the inverse {}'
                  .format(sol[we1.var], we1.varname, we2.varname))
        else:
            ok = False
            print('*** DIFFERENT VALUES :: {} = {} and {} = {}'
                  .format(we1.var, sol[we1.var], we2.var, sol[we2.var]))
```

This gives a lot of confirmation lines and finally `ok` remains `True`:

```
sage: ok
True
```

A way to argument is as follows. Each path of adjacent flips to get from $w$ to $e$ corresponds to exactly one path from $w^{-1}$ to $e$,
apply them in reversed order. This symmetry and the symmetry of the Dynkin diagram, i.e. exchanging simple reflections in
the ordered list
$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4,s_5)$ so that we get them in reversed order,
$(s_5,s_4,s_3,s_1,s_1)$, seem to be the only symmetries in the structure.

Here are some explicit values calculated above:

```
sage: [ (WE(w).var, sol[WE(w).var]) for w in w_list if w.length() < 3 ]
[(x, 0),
 (x3, 409694003392678411334887/562573226901324170862),
 (x2, 74514494034185062222904137/102388327296040999096884),
 (x4, 74514494034185062222904137/102388327296040999096884),
 (x1, 18061592492928724555567534/25597081824010249774221),
 (x5, 18061592492928724555567534/25597081824010249774221),
 (x32, 97237251774773889429499579/102388327296040999096884),
 (x34, 97237251774773889429499579/102388327296040999096884),
 (x23, 97237251774773889429499579/102388327296040999096884),
 (x21, 7932055083392903915602457/8532360608003416591407),
 (x43, 97237251774773889429499579/102388327296040999096884),
 (x42, 22612046194800912089196392/25597081824010249774221),
 (x45, 7932055083392903915602457/8532360608003416591407),
 (x31, 22229387237663671307532949/25597081824010249774221),
 (x12, 7932055083392903915602457/8532360608003416591407),
 (x41, 219680864482149559964339/252187998266110835214),
 (x53, 22229387237663671307532949/25597081824010249774221),
 (x52, 219680864482149559964339/252187998266110835214),
 (x54, 7932055083392903915602457/8532360608003416591407),
 (x51, 43713633645486016276491673/51194163648020499548442)]
sage: max([w.length() for w in W])
15
sage: [ (WE(w).var, sol[WE(w).var]) for w in w_list if w.length() > 13 ]
[(x12345123412312, 4107915597637259266379722/3656725974858607110603),
 (x23451234123121, 4107915597637259266379722/3656725974858607110603),
 (x12345123423121, 1473205929421015577091523/1312670862769756398678),
 (x12345123412321, 114943156003573670133682777/102388327296040999096884),
 (x12345234123121, 114943156003573670133682777/102388327296040999096884),
 (x123451234123121, 136181060295340/121172438079)]
```

---

**n = $\bf 7$**

This case is somehow too big for the pedestrian way of solving systems above.
(There was some handy notation for the variables, which has its merits, but in this case this is too expensive.)
So we really have to implement the linear system by building its matrix.

```
def mean_number_of_steps(n, print_A=False, print_x=False):
    W = WeylGroup(['A', n-1])
    w_list = list(W)
    w_list.sort(key=lambda w: w.length())

    w_cells = []
    w_used_values = []
    for w in w_list:
        if w in w_used_values:
            continue
        if w == W.one():
            w_cells.append( [w] )
            w_used_values.append(w)
            continue
        cell = [w, w^-1] 
        word = w.reduced_word()            
        u = W.from_reduced_word([n-j for j in word])
        cell = tuple(set([w, w^-1, u, u^-1]))
        w_cells.append(cell)
        w_used_values.extend(list(cell))

    def get_cell_index(w):
        return [ w_cells.index(cell) for cell in w_cells if w in cell ][0]

    class WA(object):
        """Associate to each w in W an instance with some more needed structure.
        """
        def __init__(self, w):
            self.w = w
            self.index = get_cell_index(w)
            if w == W.one():
                self.neighbours = []
            else:
                self.neighbours = [ get_cell_index(s*w)
                                    for s in W.simple_reflections() ]

    f, c = factorial(n), len(w_cells)
    A = matrix(QQ, c, c)
    for cell in w_cells:
        w = cell[0]    # pick a representative of the cell
        wa = WA(w)
        A[wa.index, wa.index] = 1
        for j in wa.neighbours:
            A[wa.index, j] += -1 / (n-1)
            # print(A)

    if print_A:
        print("The matrix of the system is:")
        print(A)
    b = vector(QQ, c, [1 if j != 0 else 0 for j in range(c)])
    x = A.solve_right(b)

    if print_x:
        print("The solution of the system is:")
        print(x)

    return sum([ x[j] * QQ(len(w_cells[j])) for j in range(c) ]) / f
```

Using this code, the prints

```
for n in [2..8]:
    print(f'\nn = {n}')
    M = mean_number_of_steps(n, print_A=(n < 5), print_x=(n < 5))
    print(f'\nMean number of steps is:\n  {M}\n  so approximatively {M.n()}')
```

are delivering

```
n = 2
The matrix of the system is:
[ 1  0]
[-1  1]
The solution of the system is:
(0, 1)

Mean number of steps is:
  1/2
  so approximatively 0.500000000000000
```

and

```
n = 3
The matrix of the system is:
[   1    0    0    0]
[-1/2    1 -1/2    0]
[   0 -1/2    1 -1/2]
[   0    0   -1    1]
The solution of the system is:
(0, 5, 8, 9)

Mean number of steps is:
  35/6
  so approximatively 5.83333333333333
```

and

```
n = 4
The matrix of the system is:
[   1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
[-1/3    1    0 -1/3 -1/3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
[-1/3    0    1 -2/3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
[   0 -1/3    0    1    0 -1/3 -1/3    0    0    0    0    0    0]
[   0 -2/3    0    0    1    0    0 -1/3    0    0    0    0    0]
[   0    0    0 -1/3    0    1    0    0 -2/3    0    0    0    0]
[   0    0    0 -2/3    0    0    1    0 -1/3    0    0    0    0]
[   0    0    0    0 -1/3    0    0    1 -2/3    0    0    0    0]
[   0    0    0    0    0 -1/3 -1/3    0    1    0 -1/3    0    0]
[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 -1/3    0    1 -2/3    0    0]
[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 -1/3 -1/3    1    0 -1/3]
[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 -2/3    0    0    1 -1/3]
[   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 -2/3 -1/3    1]
The solution of the system is:
(0, 625/28, 341/14, 981/28, 405/14, 1153/28, 1081/28, 274/7, 171/4, 621/14, 1273/28, 629/14, 324/7)

Mean number of steps is:
  1019/28
  so approximatively 36.3928571428571
```

and

```
n = 5

Mean number of steps is:
  73483980061/379029420
  so approximatively 193.874079909153
```

and

```
n = 6

Mean number of steps is:
  1105216051055620235300660929/1023883272960409990968840
  so approximatively 1079.43559607146
```

and

```
n = 7

Mean number of steps is:
  214998640399563504565106261781990833196638436647758234442887215473549887803722305593765999513740842990149079
  /
  31218641703910975710483919230896568944120659862343614701479235239401027577533129044990591113216494809020
  so approximatively 6886.86722627747
```

(with a manually rearranged fraction...) and

```
n = 8
```

(... still working ...)

---

I have to stop here, this was a hard day's night, and the next similar day has started...

Comment: Very impressive! I didn't think that permutation groups and group theory in general would be the solution, and it was fun to learn a little bit of group theory along the way. That being said, seeing that the estimated number of swaps is ultimately the solution to a system of equations, it seems unlikely that there will be a sensible closed form. I initially thought that the estimated swaps would be $O(n!)$ but the numbers suggest otherwise, which makes me wonder if an asymptotic bound is possible. Nevertheless, great job. Also, what is a Weyl Group? MathWorld and Wikipedia don't help.

Comment: A Weyl group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_group is a special case of a Coxeter group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group . In this case, the structure of the symmetric group needed to solve the problem (well, at least to group some simple "cells" to get linear systems of a smaller size - that is now the start of a new problem) is the structure of a Weyl / Coxeter group. We need to write each permutation minimally in terms of simple reflexions. I was expecting to get a connection to the representation theory of the symmetric groups, but this is not the case... the *left* Bruhat...

Comment: ... order is the order needed. So there is no connection e.g. to the representation theory of the symmetric groups involving for instance Young diagrams and standard tableaux.

Comment: Regarding the asymptotics, there are some other problems considering such a random walk, rather a similar one where one is allowed to pause at one point with a certain probability. The Brownian movement is similar on the same Bruhat graph, but the problem is completely diferent, it regards the **mixing time** - an answer to the question: Place the cards $1,2,\dots,n$ on a table in this order. At each step swap two adjacent cards. How many steps are needed to have a "good mixing" - i.e. so that we are in expectation close to the uniform distribution. Here are some links for this...

Comment: Jonason, Mixing times for the interchange process, https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6916, White, The weak Bruhat order and... , https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.04098.pdf. There is also a wiki page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_mixing_time - and there are some papers of Diaconis on the subject (i remember, cannot find now). A reference that may fit best is: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.3873.pdf, Lacoin, Mixing Time and Cutoff for the Adjacent transposition... There are **roughly** between $$O(n^3)\text{ and }O(n^3\log n)$$ steps needed to mix the deck. So i'd expect also this asymptotic...